# MongoDB Aggregation with match shows all the records

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have json object as following.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("123209sfekjern"),
"Name" : "Test1",
"Orders" : [ 
    {
        "Date" : "2020-05-05",
        "Total" : "100.00"
    }, 
    {
        "Date" : "2020-05-10",
        "Total" : "110.00"
    }, 
    {
        "Date" : "2020-05-11",
        "Total" : "100.00"
    }, 
    {
        "Date" : "2020-05-14",
        "Total" : "110.00"
    }, 
    {
        "Date" : "2020-05-20",
        "Total" : "100.00"
    }, 
    {
        "Date" : "2020-05-15",
        "Total" : "100.00"
    }, 
    {
        "Date" : "2020-05-12",
        "Total" : "110.00"
    }, 
    {
        "Date" : "2020-05-18",
        "Total" : "100.00"
    }, 
    {
        "Date" : "2020-05-31",
        "Total" : "110.00"
    }
]
```

}

I need customername, orders.Date and Order.Total for all the orders which is greater than 100.00

I tried following query..

```
db.Customers.aggregate
    (
    [
        {
            $match: {
                $and: [
                    {"Orders.Date":{$gte:"2020-05-15"}},//ISODate('2020-05-15 10:00:00.000Z')
                    { "Orders.Total": { $gte:  "100.00" } },
                    ]
            }
        },
        { $project: { _id:0, Name: 1, "Orders.Total": 1, "Orders.Date": 1} },
    ]
    )
```

The above query returns all the records. I m still beginner and learning mongodb.
any help would be appreciated.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$match` filters on a document level so entire document will be returned if at least one subdocument matches your conditions. In order to filter a nested array you need [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/):

```
db.Customers.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            Name: 1,
            Orders: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$Orders",
                    cond: {
                        $and: [
                            { $gte: [ "$$this.Date", "2020-05-15" ] },
                            { $gte: [ "$$this.Total", "100.00" ] },
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mOt_FqWnHwN)